# renderPlotly Hide ggplot2 line by default

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

```
library(plotly)

dat1 <- data.frame(
sex = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
total_bill = c(13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42)
)

p <- ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, group=sex,color=sex)) +
geom_line() +
geom_point()

ggplotly(p)
```

I want to hide one line by default so that the user can click on it anytime and make it visible on the plot itself.
I am rendering the above plot in shiny using "renderPlotly".
Is there any option already existing I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following line solved the issue.

```
style(ggplotly(p),visible="legendonly", traces = 1)
```